# Text To Speech Api

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm porting an app from Android/iOS and it uses text-to-speech.

Anything like this available for windows phone?

I tried the Bing/Microsoft Translator APIs but they dont work and rumour says they are deprecated: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259727/Text-to-speech-in-windows-phone7

Nuance is out of the question, as their fees are ridiculous.

Thanks in advance!
swine

Answer (score 0):

They do work. The Bing API is deprecated for use on Microsoft Translator services, the new format is to obtain tokens.
I was able to implement a library for this, here:

http://msttokenforwp7.codeplex.com/
obtaining tokens.

http://ttsforwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/
text-to-speech library

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows Phone 8, there is now a build in TTS engine. More details can be found in the [official MSDN documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207057%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).